# Nested Nuxt instances

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Not really a code problem more a discussion/brainstroming-post.
I would like to build some light CMS in Vue/Nuxt, which will output a static website in the end.

So I thought about going for one Nuxt-page (does not have to be a Nuxt-page necessarily) containing all the CMS-related stuff and handle the actual website inside a `nuxt-child` component to keep code tidy. 
Problem is, that i can not access the inner Nuxt page, so any editing will be impossible (I want to achieve some simple inline-editing).

For visualization the editor of [webflow](https://webflow.com/editor) may be helpful ([Directlink to the video](https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/videos/editor_add_new_content_v1.7b8076c3ee.mp4)). What i want to achieve is a similar version. I would like to have the page separated from the CMS. The CMS would be the lower bottom-bar and provide stuff like the editor for the inline-editing.

Currently my best solution was to define the editing directly inside the page, which is working, but needs to be stripped out for production and makes a future separation impossible.

Is there any solution for this? Or am I thinking the wrong way?
Can I link both instances with a common vuex-store?

Answer (score 0):

You could created two seperate components, one for editing and one for rendering.
These could utilize components themselves to keep the overhead to a minimun.

You could also use the same component, but lazy load the editor features based on some condition like:

1. If youre fine with having the Editor only available during development you can create an env variable and check for `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`
2. Another way would be to have some sort of authorization that combined with `v-if` would show the editor or hide it.